# Micro Frontend - A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to build a POC for Micro Frontend using Angular and Webpack Module Federation.
In this, I have created a shell app and another mfe1 app and rendering that mfe1 on a specific route hit and it is working as expected and rendering the app. Now, I am trying to create another app called mfe2 and render it. In this mfe2, I am creating a web component using Angular elements and rendering that in the shell app. When I do that, I am facing the following issue

> Error: A platform with a different configuration has been created.
> Please destroy it first.

when the following code is executing

```
import('mfe2/web-component')
    .then(_ => console.debug(`element loaded!`))
    .catch(err => console.error(`error loading `, err));
```

I don't understand where the exact issue is. I am adding the required code below.

***MFE2:***

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const ce = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('mfe2-elem', ce);
  }

}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "mfe2",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },   
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      
        // For remotes (please adjust)
        name: "mfe2",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          './web-component': './src/bootstrap.ts',
        },        
        
        // For hosts (please adjust)
        // remotes: {
        //     "mfe1": "mfe1@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",

        // },

        shared: {
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        }
        
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

***SHELL:***

rendering it in a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mfe2element',
  templateUrl: './mfe2element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mfe2element.component.scss']
})
export class Mfe2elementComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild('vc', { read: ElementRef, static: true })
  vc!: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    import('mfe2/web-component')
    .then(_ => console.debug(`element loaded!`))
    .catch(err => console.error(`error loading `, err));

    // await import('mfe1/web-components');
    // const element = document.createElement('mfe1-element');
    // document.body.appendChild(element);

    const element = document.createElement('mfe2-elem');
    this.vc.nativeElement.appendChild(element);

  }

}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "shell"
  },
  optimization: {
    // Only needed to bypass a temporary bug
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        // For remotes (please adjust)
        // name: "shell",
        // filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        // exposes: {
        //     './Component': './/src/app/app.component.ts',
        // },        
        
        // For hosts (please adjust)
        remotes: {
            "mfe1": "mfe1@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",
            "mfe2": "mfe2@http://localhost:4000/remoteEntry.js",
        },

        shared: {
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        }
        
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks...

Comment: When you created your `mfe2`, were you able to use the Angular CLI to generate `mfe2`, or did you have to tediously create `mfe2` and all of its files by hand? I'm currently trying to figure out how to add more remotes to my Module Federation micro frontend. My question is here if you'd like credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171760/how-to-create-a-new-micro-frontend-remote-using-angular-cli-webpack-5-module-f

Answer (score 5):

Taken the solution from here:
https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/47#issuecomment-845145887

Per shared Angular version, we are only allowed to create one platform. To remember that there is already a shared platform for our version, we could put it into a global dictionary mapping the version number to the platform instance:

```
const ngVersion = require('../package.json').dependencies['@angular/core']; // better just take the major version 

(window as any).plattform = (window as any).plattform || {};
let platform = (window as any).plattform[ngVersion];
if (!platform) {
  platform = platformBrowser();
  (window as any).plattform[ngVersion] = platform; 
}
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Adding this to the bootstrap.ts in both the shell and mfe will make the mfe reuse an existing platform instead of trying to create a new instance, which will lead to the error you're experiencing.

Comment: Note here, this is for each *major* version. Which means if your `package.json` references `@angular/core: "~12.1.4"` it will NOT work with a MFE that has version set at `@angular/core: "~12.2.0"` you need to reference versions as major versions ONLY in `package.json`. i.e. `@angular/core: "^12.0.0"`

Comment: can anyone help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958591/nx-mfe-angular-module-federation-not-able-to-access-remote-micro-front-end