# How to create a new remote using Angular CLI? (Webpack 5 Module Federation micro frontends)

Tags: angular, typescript, architecture, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

In an `Angular 12` project called `myShell`, I've implemented an `nx` monorepo, then defined my project as a `Webpack 5 Module Federation` micro frontend `shell` using the command `ng add @angular-architects/module-federation --project myShell --port 4200`.

Now I'd like to use the `Angular CLI` to generate a new micro frontend `remote`, which I'll name `mfe1`. How would I accomplish this with the `nx` or `ng` CLI? For example, if I navigate to my `apps` folder (which contains the `myShell` project) and do an `ng new mfe1`, I get the error message: `The new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a project definition was found at ...filepath/angular.json`. I also can't run an `ng g c`, since an Angular micro frontend app is more than a simple component.

Is there an `Angular CLI` command that I can use to create a new micro frontend remote, or must each remote application be created tediously by hand?

Comment: In my case, I created each app separately into their own folders. In shell, I did all the webpack configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng new` command will create a new workspace. So you can't use it inside a folder alread containing an angular.json file.

You can create a new angular project inside an existing workspace with the command `ng g application`

For exemple :

```
ng g application mfe1 --routing --style=scss
```